# How do I select individual image for a favorite icon with onPressed ()?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, flutter-onpressed

Here is the entire code. I simply want the heart icon to change color when selected as favorite, then push the saved favorite item to a saved favorites page. I have no idea  how to do it with stream builder.

ERROR is : In this code, when I click on a image icon, all image's icon get
selected as favorite.

```
 class CloudAlbum extends StatefulWidget {

 static const routeName = '/album';

  @override
 _CloudAlbumState createState() => _CloudAlbumState();
}

 class _CloudAlbumState extends State<CloudAlbum> {

  @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentUser();
  }

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser ;
  _getCurrentUser() async {
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      try {
        if (user != null) {
          setState(() {
            loggedInUser = user;
            print(loggedInUser.email);
            print(loggedInUser.uid);
            final email = loggedInUser.email;
            return email;
        });
       }
      } catch(e) {
         print(e);
     }
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String email = "";
      setState(() {
        email = loggedInUser.email;
      });
    //final imgid = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
    final favImg = Provider.of<FavImg>(context, listen: false);

    var users = Firestore.instance.collection('abc').document('xyz').collection(email).snapshots();

      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: users,
        builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final docs = streamSnapshot.data.documents;
         //List<bool> _isFavorited = List<bool>.generate(docs.length, (_) => false);
          print(docs);
          return GridView.builder(
             itemCount: docs.length,
             itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
               Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                 child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: GridTile(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            //   FullImage.routeName);
                          },
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: docs[index]['id'],
                              child: FadeInImage(
                                placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
                                image: NetworkImage(docs[index]['imgurl']),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        footer: GridTileBar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                           leading:
                           Consumer<FavImg>(
                             builder: (ctx, favImg, _) =>
                          //       IconButton(
                          //         onPressed: () => setState(()
                          //         => _isFavorited[index]= !_isFavorited[index]),
                          //         icon: _isFavorited[index]
                          //             ? Icon(Icons.star)
                          //             : Icon(Icons.star_border),
                          //       ),
                             IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                        
                                favImg.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                                size: 35.0,
                              ),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              onPressed: () {
                                favImg.toggleFavoriteStatus(
                                  docs[index]['id'],
                                 
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                  ),
                );
            }
          );
        }
  }
```

favimg.dart

```
 class FavImg with ChangeNotifier {

  final String imageUrl;
  final String id;
  bool isFavorite;

  FavImg({

    @required this.imageUrl,
    @required this.id,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });
 void toggleFavoriteStatus(String id) {
  
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

ERROR is : In this code, when i click on a image icon, all image's icon get selected as favorite.

Comment: Hey did you fix this, if so, could you provide it as an answer to this post? If not, could you provide more information on the "docs" to keep troubleshooting?

Comment: no, I didn't get any solution